# Editable tooltip in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am just wondering, is it possible to have a `ToolTip` which content could be edited?

For example when you focus a `TextBox`, the `ToolTip` to pop and if I clicked, the content to be editable. E.g. if the `ToolTip` contains description of an item, this description to be editable and then stored in the database, so that next time the `ToolTip` will show the new description.

If it isn't possible, is there another way for this to be implemented?

Comment: An editable tooltip is called a form.

Comment: You can have a hidden textbox and use it as tooltip. Once clicked, you can edit it. If not clicked, you can use timer to hide it. Or better yet, make a user control with label and textbox, timer, all built in. When edit, make textbox on top, when show, use label on top and timer to hide the whole control once user no longer has mouse over it, or any similar user actions. Will take you an hour to develop the whole thing

Comment: @LarsTech I got to the same conclusion, I think that it's best that way. If you move your comment to an answer I'll accept it. Thank you to both of you for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of a [ToolTip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip):

> The tooltip or infotip or a hint is a common graphical user interface element. It is used in conjunction with a cursor, usually a pointer. The user hovers the pointer over an item, without clicking it, and a tooltip may appear—a small "hover box" with information about the item being hovered over.

So it's information only.  If you want to make the contents editable, that would require using a form, with a TextBox, etc.

Assuming the tip is meant to help the user, it doesn't make much sense to let that user edit the contents of that help information.